# Как в eclipse добавить кнопки работы с буфером обмена на главный тулбар?

Tags: android, eclipse

В `eclipse android` (перспектива `Java`) отсутствуют кнопки работы с буфером `Copy`, `Paste`, `Cut`.

Справка по эклипсу отсылает в меню `Window-Perspective-Customize Perspective` там некоторые узлы соответствуют пункта меню, например `File` и должен был бы быть по логике пункт `Edit`, который наверное нужно было бы включить, но нет ничего похожего.

Comment: Не по теме, но ADT Plugin не поддерживается с середины 15-го года, поэтому на Eclipse под Android лучше не писать.